# Write into website cell using c# or WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very strange request that might upset some of you, anyway I want to write text or numbers in the website using C# or wpf software.

What I want is I pass string or number to the website when I press for example F11 on the keyboard and that number or string can be from a textbox.

Assume the following is Grid on a website:

[image: ABC Website]

Now I want to pass 0.01233 from textbox, to the highlighted cell in the website using c#.

Can anyone please how this can be achieved or at least guide me which direction I should go and achieve this.

***Please Note I am not a developer of website and I have no control on website, I cannot write script on website***

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before, though I can't seem to find my old code. WPF has a [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser) control. You can use the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document) property to access elements of the webpage an (if I recall correctly) execute scripts assosiated with those elements.

Of course it goes without saying that this would be a bodge at best, since any change made to the website could break your code.

Also, this forces you to use the WPF `WebBrowser` instead of your browser of choice.

Comment: would it be possible for you to share code what have you done and how ?

Comment: @percydeveloper I will if I can find it. I think I did this work on a different computer so I don't have the source code to hand.

Comment: Actually the website on which I am working is private otherwise I could have shared the link, the website is developed in flash player and we can't inspect element as it is protected. That's why I am not able to understand how this can be achieved.